# WPF Storyboard issue

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In the following template, the button is displayed with Normal image when the application is started, but when the mouse is over, the button doesn't get changed to mouse over image.
Appreciate your help!!! I want some solution without major changes in the design.

Comment: Since this is a custom control, we can't really help without seeing the relevant portions of your control's code.  I'm sure your Image properties are DependencyProperties, but what class are you deriving from, when do you transition to the other VSM states, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.. I should be having the Opacity like below.. not as listed in the code above..

```
<Border x:Name="imgNormal" Opacity="0">
```